# rspec variable across specs

Tags: ruby, rspec

In rpsec I have an instance of a class I have initiated in the `spec_helper`. I need each of the spec files to be able to obtain the variable for usage.

What is the cleanest method of going about this?

For clarification. The instance of this variable must be created in the `spec_helper`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class method on your helper class to always return the same instance.

In your spec helper:

```
class MyTestClass
   def self.test_class
     @my_test_instance ||= begin
       my_test = self.new
       my_test.some_value = 'this is the spec value I want everywhere'
       my_test
     end
   end
end
```

Then in your specs:

```
describe MyAwesomeClass do 
  let(:the_test_instance) { MyTestClass.test_class }
  it 'does something' do 
    expect(...) # Use the instance somehow
  end
end
```

Comment: this will not work as the variable isn't created in the spec helper.

Comment: This should be exactly what you need. The first time you would call `MyClass.test_class` then the instance will be created, you can easily have a line below the class definition that just does that. Every subsequent call to to `MyClass.test_class` will return the exact same instance, due to the memoization in the method.

Comment: It's just a singleton. I would argue that it isn't particularly a clean means at throwing around an instance. It will make it very difficult to test that class.

Comment: You want a solution that is DRY, which is why you even asked the question. The singleton is an instance of a class, which you say you want all over your spec suite. Having an instance of anything everywhere in your spec suite isn't clean in itself. This encapsulates it at least to the responsibility of one model. If you'd like to just do whatever, would setting a global variable `$test_class` in `spec_helper` be more your style? Is that more "clean"?

Comment: The question is more asking is there a way to store a variable in the rspec namespace, for instance in its config. Rather than creating another singleton or static module. And it is probably best to stay away from global variables.